# Resolve the container itself with Unity

Tags: unity-container

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) when using Unity the container itself can be resolved as a dependency. I am trying to find an example on how this can be achieved but could not find any.

Comment: If you have a dependency of type IUnityContainer it should be resolved to the container itself. Didn't that work for you? Note that it's not recommended to have a dependency on a container, and it's usually better to have a dependency on a Func<T> instead to build new objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use case for this is when you implement a factory inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This factory can callback into the container to resolve the types it needs:

```cs
private class UnitySomeServiceFactory : ISomeServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnitySomeServiceFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {    
        this.container = container;
    }

    public ISomeService Create(SomeServiceType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case SomeServiceType.Blue: return this.container.Resolve<BlueService>();
            case SomeServiceType.Pink: return this.container.Resolve<PinkService>();
            case SomeServiceType.Red: return this.container.Resolve<RedService>();
            default: throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that taking a dependency on the container from anywhere but the Composition Root is discouraged.

Comment: Could you add a short example on how would you use the factory in code? Thank you.

Comment: @user379429: Step 1: Inject the `ISomeServiceFactory` into a constructor of a class. Step 2: Call the factory's `Create` method somewhere in that class.